# HTML: Variation of table data (td) element count (without colspan)

Tags: html, html-table

Is it legal - according to HTML-specifications - to generate tables, that vary in their td-element count per row without any specification of the colspan-attribute?

Can this table be considered valid HTML?

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>c</td>
   </tr>
</table>

<!-- Output: -->

---------
| a | b |
---------
| c |     <-- Missing cell.
-----
```

All browsers I know render this as predicted. However, they often try to render bad syntax, so this behaviour is not sufficient to tell if the code above is actually valid HTML.

**Background:** I am writing a PHP class which should render tables having varying counts of `td`-elements per row. The class would need to render the table by finding the row having the most `td`-elements as a reference in order to produce valid HTML-syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late answer, but found this question when searching for this, so thought I'd post the answer for future readers after I figured it out.

According to the [w3 table model specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#table-model): **Yes, this is valid syntax for a table**.

In summary, the `xwidth` of the table is incremented as-needed as the browser processes each element that comprises the table. There's no specific mention in the spec about whether or not this is legal, however the defined *and required* algorithm for how browsers should form a table should handle this scenario without issue.

Additionally, putting the following into the [W3 Markup validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) **successfully validates with no issues, but does produce a warning**: `Line 14, Column 17: A table row was 1 columns wide, which is less than the column count established by the first row (2).`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>a</td>
                <td>b</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>c</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```